# tseries: get.hist.quote() gives wrong result

Tags: r, time-series

According to the following code, the historical quotes of `ROG.VX` are constant in the chosen time period. However, under http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ROG.VX&a=08&b=09&c=2011&d=02&e=28&f=2012&g=d&z=66&y=132 one can check that they are not (see the screenshot). What's wrong?

```
require(tseries)
hq <- get.hist.quote(instrument="ROG.VX", start="2011-09-09", end="2012-03-28",
                     quote="Close", provider="yahoo", drop=TRUE)
plot(hq) # => constant
stopifnot(hq==138.3) # => constant 138.3
```

[image]

Comment: [Cross-posted on R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-November/329927.html)

Comment: Also: what did you do to ascertain that it is an R issue, as opposed ton an error in the Yahoo! backend?

Comment: They look constant at 138.3 to me both on the page you linked and R code.

Comment: Dirk: I am not sure how I could further check that. I just went to the yahoo finance webpage and saw the correct quotes.
Sebastian: I attached a screenshot, the quotes are not equal on the yahoo finance webpage

Comment: As Achim Zeilis correctly pointed out on r-help, the "Download to Spreadsheet" provides the wrong data (although the webpage shows the correct data), so it's indeed a Yahoo! Finance problem. Sorry, I should have figured this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Yahoo issue.

If we look at the info that `get.hist.quote()` returns, we can see that it is asking yahoo via http to provide a csv.  We can easily paste the same URL into a browser to download the csv and confirm those are the numbers R is getting.  And changing the dates, we can see there is a clear loss of data in the ROG.VX time series but not in a comparison time series (IBM):

```
> rog <- get.hist.quote(instrument="ROG.VX", start="2010-06-10", end="2012-03-28",
+                      provider="yahoo", drop=TRUE)
trying URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ROG.VX&a=5&b=10&c=2010&d=2&e=28&f=2012&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=ROG.VX&x=.csv'
Content type 'text/csv' length unknown
opened URL
downloaded 6439 bytes

> ibm <- get.hist.quote(instrument="ibm", start="2010-06-10", end="2012-03-28",
+                      provider="yahoo", drop=TRUE)
trying URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ibm&a=5&b=10&c=2010&d=2&e=28&f=2012&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=ibm&x=.csv'
Content type 'text/csv' length unknown
opened URL
downloaded 24 Kb

> test<-merge(ibm,rog)
> plot(test)
```

[image]